# Declaring char variable breaks program

Tags: c, tga

I am exploring .tga files.

I have fully working code that looks like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

const int letterHeight = 34;
const int spacer = 5;

typedef struct{
    uint8_t idlength;
    uint8_t colourmaptype;
    uint8_t datatypecode;
    uint16_t colourmaporigin;
    uint16_t colourmaplength;
    uint8_t colourmapdepth;
    uint16_t x_origin;
    uint16_t y_origin;
    uint16_t width;
    uint16_t height;
    uint8_t bitsperpixel;
    uint8_t imagedescriptor;
} TGA_Header;

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t B;
    uint8_t G;
    uint8_t R;
} Pixel;

typedef struct{
    TGA_Header header;
    Pixel* pixels;
    int width;
    int height;
} Image;


void readHeader(TGA_Header* header, FILE* input_F){
    fread(&header->idlength, sizeof(header->idlength), 1, input_F);
    fread(&header->colourmaptype, sizeof(header->colourmaptype), 1, input_F);
    fread(&header->datatypecode, sizeof(header->datatypecode), 1, input_F);
    fread(&header->colourmaporigin, sizeof(header->colourmaporigin), 1, input_F);
    fread(&header->colourmaplength, sizeof(header->colourmaplength), 1, input_F);
    fread(&header->colourmapdepth, sizeof(header->colourmapdepth), 1, input_F);
    fread(&header->x_origin, sizeof(header->x_origin), 1, input_F);
    fread(&header->y_origin, sizeof(header->y_origin), 1, input_F);
    fread(&header->width, sizeof(header->width), 1, input_F);
    fread(&header->height, sizeof(header->height), 1, input_F);
    fread(&header->bitsperpixel, sizeof(header->bitsperpixel), 1, input_F);
    fread(&header->imagedescriptor, sizeof(header->imagedescriptor), 1, input_F);
}


void writeHeader(TGA_Header* header, FILE* output_F){
    fwrite(&header->idlength, sizeof(header->idlength), 1, output_F);
    fwrite(&header->colourmaptype, sizeof(header->colourmaptype), 1, output_F);
    fwrite(&header->datatypecode, sizeof(header->datatypecode), 1, output_F);
    fwrite(&header->colourmaporigin, sizeof(header->colourmaporigin), 1, output_F);
    fwrite(&header->colourmaplength, sizeof(header->colourmaplength), 1, output_F);
    fwrite(&header->colourmapdepth, sizeof(header->colourmapdepth), 1, output_F);
    fwrite(&header->x_origin, sizeof(header->x_origin), 1, output_F);
    fwrite(&header->y_origin, sizeof(header->y_origin), 1, output_F);
    fwrite(&header->width, sizeof(header->width), 1, output_F);
    fwrite(&header->height, sizeof(header->height), 1, output_F);
    fwrite(&header->bitsperpixel, sizeof(header->bitsperpixel), 1, output_F);
    fwrite(&header->imagedescriptor, sizeof(header->imagedescriptor), 1, output_F);
}


void image_load(Image* image, const char* path){
    FILE* input_F = fopen(path, "rb");
        
    readHeader(&image->header, input_F);

    image->width = image->header.width;
    image->height = image->header.height;

    image->pixels = (Pixel*) malloc(sizeof(Pixel) * image->header.width * image->header.height);
    fread(image->pixels, sizeof(Pixel), image->header.width * image->header.height, input_F);

    fclose(input_F);
}

void image_create(Image* image, const char* path){
    FILE* output_F = fopen(path, "wb");
        
    writeHeader(&image->header, output_F);
    fwrite(image->pixels, sizeof(Pixel), image->header.width * image->header.height, output_F);

    fclose(output_F);
}


void load_letters(Image (*letters)[26], const char* f){
    char path[101];

    for(int i=0; i<26; i++){
        strcpy(path, f);
        strcat(path, "/");
        char c[2] = {(char)(65+i), '\0'};
        strcat(path, c);
        strcat(path, ".tga\0");

        image_load(&(*letters)[i], &path[0]);
    }
}


void drawLetter(Image* image, Image* letter, int X, int Y){
    Y += letterHeight - letter->height;

    int letter_y = letter->height;
    int letter_x = letter->width;
    int image_x = image->width;

    for(int y=0; y<letter_y; y++){
        for(int x=0; x<letter_x; x++){
            if(letter->pixels[y*letter_x+x].R != (uint8_t)0 || letter->pixels[y*letter_x+x].G != (uint8_t)0 || letter->pixels[y*letter_x+x].B != (uint8_t)0){
                image->pixels[(y+Y)*image_x+(x+X)] = letter->pixels[y*letter_x+x];
            }
        }
    }
}


void drawString(Image* image, Image (*letters)[26], char (*text)[101], int Y){
    int dejToSzajzym = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<strlen((*text)); i++){
        dejToSzajzym += (*letters)[(int)(*text)[i] - 65].width;
    }
    dejToSzajzym = dejToSzajzym/2;
    dejToSzajzym = image->width/2 - dejToSzajzym;

    for(int i=0; i<strlen(*text); i++){
        if((*text)[i] != ' '){
            drawLetter(image, &(*letters)[(int)(*text)[i] - 65], dejToSzajzym, Y);
            dejToSzajzym += (*letters)[(int)(*text)[i] - 65].width;
        }else{
            dejToSzajzym += 10;
        }
    }
}
    
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    Image* image;
    Image letters[26];

    image_load(image, "img1.tga");
    load_letters(&letters, "font");

    /*
    char buffer[100];
    */

    drawString(image, &letters, "LOL", 5);
    image_create(image, "image.tga");

    free(image->pixels);
    image->pixels = NULL;
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++){
        free(letters[i].pixels);
        letters[i].pixels = NULL;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

But when I write the declaration of `buffer` as shown (could be anywhere in `main`) the program immediately breaks.
It doesn´t even need to do anything.

**error:**

```
Unable to open 'memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S': Unable to read file '/build/glibc-YYA7BZ/glibc-
2.31/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S' 
(Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '/build/glibc-YYA7BZ/glibc-2.31/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memmove-vec-unaligned-erms.S').
```

BTW: Isn't there any easier way to copy the header data?

Comment: `Image* image;` is an uninitialized pointer. Reading data into whatever random location it points to is undefined behavior. The crash you see is because you're writing to memory that does not belong to you. Instead of a pointer in `main` use an instance of the struct and pass its address to the functions. `Image image; image_load(&image, "img1.tga");` etc.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by [Retired Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920069/retired-ninja) in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74586171/declaring-char-variable-breaks-program/74586879#comment131656273_74586171), your primary problem is that `Image *image;` doesn't initialize `image` to point anywhere in particular.  You pass the uninitialized pointer to `image_load()`, which then scribbles on memory — and you've no idea where.  This is all undefined behaviour.  Adding the variable `buffer` moves something around and changes the behaviour, but it is still undefined — anything goes and any (mis-)behaviour is valid, especially crashes.  You must fix that!  One way would be to change the definition to `Image image;` and pass `&image` to `image_load()` and the other functions that expect an `Image *`.

> BTW: Isn't there any easier way to copy the header data?

Yes, there is, and there are a couple of ways to do it.  The fundamental observation is that you could write the header with `fwrite(header, sizeof(*header), 1, fp)`, and read it with `fread(header, sizeof(*header), 1, fp)`.

However, with the data structure as currently defined, there is some padding in the structure — one byte after `datatypecode` and another after `colourmapdepth`.  If you moved `colourmapdepth` after `datatypecode` (or anywhere near the start of the structure before the first `uint16_t` member), you'd save two bytes in memory and have no padding bytes on disk.  OTOH, there's not a lot of harm in the padding bytes being read/written.  It isn't clear to me whether you're dealing with an externally imposed header structure or whether you're free to modify it.

The best way to avoid padding in a structure is to put the most stringently aligned types at the start of the structure (`uint16_t` is more stringently aligned than `uint8_t`) and less stringently aligned types at the end.   That normally avoids holes in the structure.  There can still be padding at the end of the structure even so.

Answer (score -2):

The compiler is attempting to call `memmove` and can't find it because you're running with no libraries.

Assuming you're doing what I think you're doing, the best way is to provide it. In another file, declare `memmove` like so.

```
void *memmove(void *sm, const void *tm, size_t n)
{
    char *s = (char *)sm;
    const char *t = (const char *)tm;
    if (s > t) {
        s += n;
        t += n;
        while (n--)
           *--s = *--t;
    } else {
        while (n--)
           *s++ = *t++;
    }
    return sm;
}
```

You may have to fiddle with the declaration to get the compiler to accept it.

Note that this is not the best possible `memmove`, it's the simplest. If it's too slow, write or obtain a faster one.

Comment: This seems like an implausible hypothesis to me.  The code includes `<string.h>` and that declares `memmove()`.  There's no obvious reason to think that `memmove()` isn't in the executable.  Rather, the problem is that the error reporting system can't find the (assembly) source code for `memmove()`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It looks like he's trying to solve the problem of he doesn't have any libraries to link against. Note also there is no memmove call in his code, so he doesn't need to declare it.